# Choosing another datepicker dialog on Android

Tags: android, datepicker

I have an private App that works great till I upgraded my phone to Android 7.
The issue is I need picker to choose only month and year (with no day).
On the old Android versions, I had this one:
[image: No month]

but - after the upgrade, all I can choose is:
[image: No working]

Is there a way to set the picker in the app to be the old style, or any other idea to select only month and year?

I tried the theme style parameter on the constructor like this:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog ,listener,
                        c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

But it did not helped either, I am getting same results (different theme):

[image: Black cal]

Why does it change in the first place without me as developer setting it to the new picker?

You can see the clean code here:
[GitHub DatePicker test](https://github.com/gabik/AndroidDatePickerTest)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
     AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,this,year,month,day);

datepickerdialog.OnDateSetListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
      // arg1 = year
      // arg2 = month
      // arg3 = day     
   }
};
```

Comment: Not works, same results..

Comment: remove the old import of v7 and again import the datePicker with v4

Comment: how can I do it? I am importing: "import android.app.DatePickerDialog;"

Comment: ok wait see my new answer

Answer (score 0):

When creating `DatePickerDialog`, you can set the old style for it

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import java.util.Calendar;

...
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog ,listener,
        c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

dpd.show();
dpd.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Here is the result when I test on Device Android 6 (API 23)
[image]

Comment: Tried that, did not helped. Please see the question, I updated it with screenshot

Comment: @gabi I have updated my answer, please check it again

Comment: I am using Android 7 now.. do you think it is related?

Comment: so please update your question. in your question you say `I upgraded my phone to Android 6`. :(. also have you test this code in device android 7, make sure you use my code and my import

Comment: @Phan-Van-Lihn updated, I used your code in new project but still no help :( - see code here: https://github.com/gabik/AndroidDatePickerTest

Answer (score 0):

```
private DatePickerDialog createDialogWithoutDateField() {
    DatePickerDialog onlyMonthdAndYearPicker = new DatePickerDialog(this, null, 2014, 1, 24);
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field[] datePickerDialogFields = dpd.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (java.lang.reflect.Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) {
            if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {
                datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
                DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField.get(onlyMonthdAndYearPicker);
                java.lang.reflect.Field[] datePickerFields = datePickerDialogField.getType().getDeclaredFields();
                for (java.lang.reflect.Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                    Log.i("test", datePickerField.getName());
                    if ("mDaySpinner".equals(datePickerField.getName())) {
                        datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                        Object dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                        ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return onlyMonthdAndYearPicker;
}
```

and Call this method

```
 createDialogWithoutDateField().show();
```